# escape from par function in R

Tags: r

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
plot(return_data[,1],main="883")
plot(return_data[,2],main="857")
plot(return_data[,3],main="386")
```

After I am done using the `par` function and while I am doing my next graph, I see the following message, think I need to escape from the `par` function first before I do my next graph, any idea on how? Or generally, any commands I need to do so R knows I am done using the `par` function? Thank you so much.

What I am doing next after using the `par` function is as below:

```
highchart(type="chart")
  hc_add_series(return_data[,1],name="883")%>%
  hc_add_series(return_data[,2],name="857")%>%
  hc_add_series(return_data[,3],name="386")%>%
  hc_title(text="<b>883,386,857</b>")
```

Then error is shown:

```
Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

> class(return_data)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

Comment: Your usage of `par()` seems fine, no need to do anything else about it. The problem will be somewhere else. Does `traceback()` tell anything useful? What is `class(return_data)`?

Comment: Have you tried dev.off()

Comment: @RobertHacken, hi Rob, tried `trackback()`, no luck and please see updated question for more background info? Thanks Rob

Comment: I don't know anything about Highcharts but you might be missing the pipe operator after `highchart()`. Also, I would guess it doesn't make much sense to mix `plot()` and `highchart()`.

Comment: Try to store and restore the pars `op <- par(mfrow=c(3, 1); <plot stuff>; par(op)`. But reset everything first using `graphics.off()`.